# How do I render running text animation in Freetype?

Tags: fonts, graphics, freetype

I can't seem to find this anywhere, but is there any way in render a simple text animation using Freetype Fonts.

It should be similar to the gif below[image]

I thought about updating adding each letter to the text but that doesn't seem efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
void TextComponent::TypingTextAnimation(float dt)
{
    m_dt += dt;
    if (m_dt >= typingSpeed)
    {
        ++m_length;
        m_dt = 0.f;

        if (loop)
        {
            if (m_length > (int)text.length())
                m_length = 0;
        }
        m_length = std::clamp(m_length, 0, (int)text.length());
    }
    subtext = text.substr(0, m_length);
}
```